# Браузер с интерфейсом на CSS

Tags: css, браузер

Есть такой браузер -- Vivaldi. Разрабатывается бывшей командой Opera. Его особенность -- интерфейс на CSS и JS. В этом есть и преимущества, и недостатки.
Преимущества -- действительно обладает наивысшей кастомизацией среди браузеров (из известных мне).
Недостатки -- следствие того же CSS и JS. Пользователи жалуются на серьезные тормоза интерфейса на слабых ПК. Здесь трудно предъявить что-то разработчикам. И я согласен с ними, что мощность процессоров растет быстрее, чем сложность браузера.
Вопрос нестандартный, т.к. я могу разместить только свой предположительный код вопроса. Он работает почти так, как надо.
А полный код, и все результаты видны прямо в самом браузере. Могу предложить только видео.

В оригинале эти диалы не носятся по экрану, а стоят на своем месте, там где и должны быть. Там было простое неинтересное смещение на -1 px.

Оригинал:

```
 .dials {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.dials .dial {
  contain: style;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: left;
  touch-action: none;
  height: var(--backgroundHeight);
  width: var(--thumbnailWidth);
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: dial;

.dials-wrapper:not(.dragging-disabled) .dials .dial:hover,
.dials-wrapper:not(.dragging-disabled) .dials .dial:focus {
      margin-top:-1px;}
```

Оригинал [common.css](https://yadi.sk/d/YOZ54XxvhtEPNQ), классы в строке 11867.
Видно, что классы выбраны верно.

Вот я изменил, результат на **ВИДЕО:**.

```
 .dials-wrapper:not(.dragging-disabled) .dials .dial:hover,
 .dials-wrapper:not(.dragging-disabled) .dials .dial:focus {           
       transform-origin: center center !important;
       transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
       box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #FF0000 !important;   
       transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.9,0.5,2) 1s !important; }  

  .dials-wrapper:not(.dragging-disabled) .dials .dial {
       transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.9,0.5,2) !important; }
```

Если оставить оригинальные классы, или удалить только :not(...) -- работает одинаково.

**Express Panel**, **ВИДЕО:**
[image: Express Panel]

Чтобы вам самим проверить результат, надо загрузить [браузер](https://vivaldi.com/download/), установить его (как любой Chromium, позволяет Portable, т.е. может работать не основным браузером на новой Windows из любой папки), указать Вашу внешнюю папку с собственными стилями, положить в нее свой **name.css**.

Форум: [Modding Vivaldi](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/10549/modding-vivaldi), как это сделать. Перезапустить, смотреть результат.

Легко сказать -- измени стили и сразу все увидишь. Это если знаешь, что менять.

Страница, [Inspecting the Vivaldi UI with DevTools](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/16684/inspecting-the-vivaldi-ui-with-devtools?page=1), где показано, как инспектировать, Dev Tools для самого браузера. Покажет названия стилей этой Express Panel.

Вопрос: что еще надо изменить в оригинальном файле стилей, чтобы убрать это паразитное смещение к 1 квадрату ?.

Comment: Вы знаете, что за использование `!important;` в приличном обществе фронтенд специалистов бьют об монитор  лицом? А если серьезно, то ваша проблема явно не связана с самой анимацией на ховер, она связана с тем, что браузер не знает, что есть начальная позиция и по этому пытается вязать к первому элементу классов. Я б дебажел присваивая эффект анимации не на класс а на id. Если  мысль правильная и подключая анимацию по айдишникам проблемный эффект пропадает, то думал бы как это обойти. Возможно правильным решением будет написать с примером разработчикам браузера.

Comment: понятно, что правильно обсуждать это на их форуме. Но этот вопрос там как-то не зашел. Тем более, все модификации разрабы воспринимают как нарушение лицензии. Там не понятно -- на форуме есть целый раздел "моддинг", все меняют что захотят. Но за собственный Portable (люди уже свои DLL клепают) там банят.  Их не поймешь. Разрабы там не отвечают. Там все, кто имеют шильдик "Team" к программированию не относятся никак :). Больше трепотни, результата 0.

Comment: я думаю, будет и  без !important работать, если удалить оригинальные стили. Просто мне не понятен механизм. Вроде бы я ничего не изменил, но именно transform: rotate() убивает позиционирование. Мне там на форуме ответили "здесь все на flex, сделать ничего нельзя " :) Как-то слабо верится. Тем более, уже половина работы сделана.

Comment: У вас перегружены классами вызовы... попробуйте избавиться от родительских. Может браузер как-то на них реагирует. .dial  . Плюс... уберите всё то что не меняеться из :hover, :focus  в .dial ... В :hover, :focus надо оставлять только то что изменяеться от базового.

Comment: нет , без !important не работает. Без него никак :) . И угрозы монитором не помогут. Если оставить только внутренние классы   .dial:hover, :focus {}  работает точно так же, даже быстрее.

Comment: Если убрать все упоминания transform , то .dial стоят на своем месте, красная тень работает. Все красиво. Если добавить  transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1.0) !important;   -- сразу диалы начинают летать на встречу 1 квадрату. Хоть и без вращения. Эта   transform: ...   работает правильно, но имеет вредное влияние на позиции диалов. Где там найти их  #ID  пока не в курсе.

Comment: Так задайте элементам id ... Сначало надо понять причину, а потом устранять.

Comment: я заметил , что      transform-origin: center center !important;     интересно работает. Без нее все диалы вращаются через левую кромку, что верно -- центр вращения в точке (0,0) каждого диала. Но только левый столб вращается через середину. Значит, transform: ... видит общий для всех центр, куда и переносит все квадраты. На картинке он примерно под мышью.  Где указан этот центр ? Я чувствую, что собака там.

Comment: чтобы задать ID , это мне надо в HTML лезть ? Это не предусмотрено. И до первого обновления. А свой стиль будет работать. Это заложено в браузер.

Comment: я удалил все из оригинальных стилей, оставил только ширину и высоту (через переменные). Нормальные там программеры. Наверное,  старый код, который не убрали . А потом удивляются, что все тормозит. Ничего не меняется. Центр всех квадратов находится в центре 1 квадрата и указан где-то в другом месте. Странная ситуация, и интересная. transform-origin: относится к квадратам, а вот transform: rotate() тоже к ним, но центр вращения transform-origin: уже к ней не относится. Как это понять ?

Comment: ширина и высота тоже к диалам не относится. Рисуются через другие стили.

Comment: вот примерная структура ----  .dials .speeddial .dials-wrapper .dial {}  --- почему указывается  в .dial { transform: rotate() }  , а центр вращения относит ко внешнему элементу ? Как указать центр внутри .dial {  }   ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149237/discussion-between-serega-da-and-blackstar1991).